# Symfony : form error message not displayed

Tags: php, symfony

I'm creating a form with Symfony, its works perfectly but I have an issue with my validation, I made a field required and not blank but the error message isn't displayed when I submit the form with the input empty I don't know why

there is some part of code :

FormType :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class AnnonceurType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
      <some fields>
            ->add('phone', TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' =>[
                    new NotBlank()
                ]
            ])
     }
}
```

template of form :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
 <some fields>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.phone, 'Phone number') }} *
            {{ form_widget(form.phone, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>

        <div class="float-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                  {{ 'submit'|trans() }}
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-error">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
         </div>
   
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Someone know what's wrong with my code ? thanks you

update: solved, it was because of the required, I added a novalidate and now its ok

Answer (score 3):

The function `form_errors` will output the errors associated with an *specific field*. In this case, as the root form doesn't have any error, it shows nothing.

You can either:

- Render the error individually by field: `form_errors(form.phone)`.
- Use the option [`error_bubbling`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling) in your form fields, so the error *does* bubble up to the parent and works as you expect.

Additionally, as you seem to be using bootstrap, you can configure the [`form_theme`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-themes-to-all-forms) to use the bootstrap layout; it'll automatically output the field errors as part of the `form_label` call, although you'll lose the ability to fine control their rendering.

Comment: I tried to render the error with form_errors(form.phone), but the error still not displayed, I didn't configured the form_theme with the bootstrap layout, it is the problem ?

Comment: @yonea Try installing a theme, it should help. Add this to the beginning of the twig file `{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}`

Comment: I tried to add like you said, and in config/twig.yaml but errors message still not displayed, very strange

Comment: I solved it, it was because of the no validate